# What DBCollection WriteConcern suits for this operation

Tags: mongodb

I am using MonogoDB in my application .

I am performing a big insert operation for all the symbols present in the arraylist as shown below

I am afraid that while this insertion is big , it may block another operations , is there anyway that I can tell MongoDB that perform this insert operation in background (that is asynchronously ) means don't let other executions stop for this .

Is this possible to do?

```
public void insert(ArrayList<QuoteReportBean> quotelist) 
    {
     BasicDBList totalrecords = new BasicDBList();
     for (QuoteReportBean reportbean: quotelist) {
     BasicDBObject dbrecord = new BasicDBObject();
     dbrecord.append("custid", reportbean.getCustomerId());
     dbrecord.append("symbol", reportbean.getUniqueSymbol());
     dbrecord.append("exch", reportbean.getExchange());
     totalrecords.add(dbrecord);
     }
     WriteResult result = coll.insert(totalrecords);
     logger.error(" - " + result.toString());   
    }
```

my requiremnt is that this opeartion should be completed , but at the same time this should not block other operations .
I have seen the WriteConcern can improve perfromance in this case .

```
WriteConcern.NONE   No exceptions are raised, even for network issues.
WriteConcern.NORMAL   Write operations that use this write concern will return as soon as the message is written to the socket.
WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED Write operations that use this write concern will return as soon as the message is written to the socket.
```

collected from

http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html

I am planning to use `WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED`, is this best or are there any issues I need to take care of?

Or is there any other way for completing it asynchronously?

Comment: If you are working with multi-threading then you should not worry about this. The moment a thread is waiting for any ack, the system resource(cpu) will be given to next thread, i.e. this thread won't block other inserts of thread. For having safe write, you have to at least use `ACKNOWLEDGED`.

Answer (score 0):

writeConcern is not about the way you insert the data it's about how you get notified about insertion results. From the client perspective it may seem that your script works faster but eventually you will end-up with a stacked data on mongo side, waiting to be persisted.